# Is it possible to delete images from SO server once they've been added to an answer?

Tags: support, status-completed

I added an image to an answer which I should not have. I am replacing the image in the answer. However, the old image is still on the SO servers. Can it be removed by me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literal answer here is: no. You cannot remove an image from the imgur album.

That said, there's a few caveats:

1. The full i.stack.imgur.com album is ***not*** publicly accessible the way [http://imgur.com/r/aww](https://imgur.com/r/aww) is (as an example).
2. Images in previous revisions can be removed so as to be unrecoverable.
3. If you've accidentally uploaded images of, say, a more confidential nature, you can email `team@stackexchange.com` with an imgur deletion request. It's not a guarantee, but the team will look into the situation. If you can, please provide us with an image URL for us to track.

Comment: Thanks Aarthi. As long as there's no public access, that will suffice. It will be fine in a couple weeks... just not now. Appreciated!

Comment: I've sent an email. Hopefully, since it doesn't direct effect content now, it can be removed. Thanks!

Comment: @Scott I found (and claimed!) your email -- I've pinged a developer about this and I'll be in touch as soon as it's taken care of :)

Comment: Thanks Aarthi!!

Comment: @Scott A developer is working on removing that image from our imgur album -- in the mean time, I've permanently removed it from the revision history: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/15303/revisions

Comment: Thank you SO much!!!! I'll be more careful in the future. I really appreciate the efforts you have gone to.

Comment: @Scott Image has been removed permanently. :)

Comment: Thank you! .....